# Text decorations not getting removed (underline gets removed, but text stays decorated)

Tags: html, css

I have a link inside a div and I have set text-decoration: none; to that a tag like that:

CSS (SCSS):

```
&__link {
    &:link,
    &:visited {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="feature-box">
                    <a href="#" class="feature-box__link js--scroll-to-services">
                      <svg class="feature-box__icon feature-box__icon--1">
                        <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#sewage"/>
                      </svg>
                        <h3 class="heading-tertiary u-margin-bottom-small">Vee ja kanalisatsiooni-<br>süsteemide ehitus</h3>
                        <p class="feature-box__text">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, ipsum sapiente aspernatur.
                        </p>
                    </a>
                  </div>
```

The problem is that text-decoration: none property only removes text underline, but text still stays purple inside it like it has been visited.

Comment: Create running code snippet or Fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text color is not set by `text-decoration` property. set the `color` property to whatever color you wish.

Comment: I know text-decoration is not used to set a color- I didn't want my link to have any decorations and it automatically set my text color to purple. Anyway I had to set color: inherit; to fix the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `color: black;`. The text color is not decoration.

Answer (score 0):

Set same color to both `link` and `visited`, as shown below, it has nothing to do with `text-decoration: none`.

```
.link,
.link:link,
.link:visited {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set `color` as you want to `&.feature-box__link`

```
&.feature-box__link {
    &:link,
    &:visited {
      text-decoration: none;
      color:black;
    }
  }
```

See working code:https://jsfiddle.net/gj1cL8en/4/

Comment: tell me for more help

Answer (score 0):

[Programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612983/9191632)'s answer + the color which you are getting because of some browser defaults. You need to define your rules to override them.